# Bind aggregate function in python using postgresql and sql alchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

```
    import sqlalchemy as sa
    query = sa.text('''
        with t1 as (
            select :aggregate_fn(value), item_id 
            from items 
            where item_id = :item_id and item_time > :fromm and item_time < :until 
            group by item_id
        )
        SELECT coalesce(array_to_json(array_agg(t1)), '[]')::text::bytea FROM t1
    ''').bindparams(fromm='2018-05-16', until='2018-05-17', item_id=2, aggregate_fn='min')
    result = engine.execute(query).scalar()
    item_records = result.tobytes().decode('utf8').replace("'", '"')
    items = json.loads(item_records)
```

I have an items table containing item_id, item_time, and item_value. The question is how can I aggregate the value at run time from the python code. For instance i am using item_id at run time using bind parameters. But when I try to do the same with the aggregate functions it throws me an error.

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) syntax
>   error at or near "("

How can the aggregate function be binded at run time from python code.

Comment: You cannot parameterize functions like `min()`, only literal values.

Comment: This'd be the rare exceptional case where you do need string formatting for reasons above, if you must use textual SQL, compared to using a query builder such as, say, SQLAlchemy. If you take that route and the function parameter is coming from outside, whitelist.